# Eric Cook 'Bolivar': Should the B natural in bar 55 be B flat?

Tags: transcription, trombone

I'm studying Eric Cook's 'Bolivar' (1954) for trombone. At the end of bar 55, there is B natural that sounds way off to me. Measure 55 is the third bar shown below; the score is in tenor clef, key signature is F Maj/D min (i.e., B flat)
[image: "Bolivar" mm. 53–56]

It's at 1:03 in [this performance](https://youtu.be/17C1RSNabMc?t=60) by Alessi. It sounds more like a B flat to me, but I might be wrong. Does someone have an opinion? Is this a transcription mistake?

Comment: Agreed — B natural makes no sense there. Gotta be Bb (which I hear in the recording, too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the piece, but I assume you’re right (it is also more or less what is played in the recording). Just from a structural point the B natural would not make sense (as everything before is always a triad), and I would not expect it in the harmonic style of this piece.

Also this can easily happen if an edition is prepared with too little care, as a badly written b can be confused with a badly written natural. But it might also be an engraving error, so the guy who punched this might have just in a moment of carelessness confused the stencil.